Having multiples android folders in Flutter
I work with many different Android devices. Phones, POS, kiosks and more. They all have different requirements, from specific dependencies to Pro-guard rules and so on. But the UI, application and logic is almost the same with some variants using each other's capabilities, from printers, scanners, etc.
How do I create and maintain such a repository with the least amount of work?
